# Trying to find horror movie about portals

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction, horror

I remember seeing a horror or suspense movie where a couple are on the run from something - ghost, monster, serial killer, and they are able to travel through portals. I recall one scene where they go under a bed and end up coming out of a closet in a motel or something similar. I want to say it was a young couple, and the movie was at least 8 years old.

I think the protagonist(s) were able to quickly use closed doors and closets as a method of transportation and I remember being impressed with the camera movements/visual slight-of-hand. It's not the Adjustment Bureau, rather a dark movie like a horror or dark sci-fi. Perhaps they could move about in shadows or dark places? I know they were trying to escape something scary or evil.

Comment: Welcome to [Movies & TV](http://movies.stackexchange.com/tour). Please try to add anything that may help identification. Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions you can give?

Comment: Thank you for the tag update, Napoleon. I'm straining to remember any more details that the snippet I wrote before. I think the protagonist(s) were able to quickly use closed doors and closets as a method of transportation and I remember being impressed with the camera movements/visual slight-of-hand. It's not the Adjustment Bureau, rather a dark movie like a horror or dark sci-fi. Perhaps they could move about in shadows or dark places? I know they were trying to escape something scary or evil. That's all I've got. :/

Comment: Not much to go on, but I'm thinking 'Crossworlds' (1996) - It seems to fit your description but then again, I suspect a lot of movies might :)

Comment: Hi Dannie, thank you so much for the suggestion. I just watched the trailer for Crossworlds and that didn't seem to be the one - the one I saw was more firmly rooted in a darker genre. Though thanks for bringing up this movie because I totally remember watching that once as a teenager! (And I know I'm so super vague in my plot description - it's really all I can remember! :/)

Comment: There was also Jumper

Comment: HI Davesexcel - Jumper was another great movie, though not the specific one I was looking for. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It all sounds like [Boogeyman](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0357507/combined). It's dark horror, from 2005, contains some weird and jittery camerawork and the titular monster lurks in shadows and moves around through portals under beds and in closets; the final scenes feature a young couple going under a bed and coming out of a closet. The film starred Barry Watson, Emily Deschanel and Lucy Lawless and spawned 2 sequels ([2](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0900357/combined) & [3](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1204883/combined)). Here's the trailer: